# Problema com paginação do Wordpress - Site dentro de uma pasta, mas que é acessado pela raiz do domínio

Tags: wordpress, paginação

Preciso muito da ajuda de vocês, sou iniciante em Wordpress e embora eu tenha alguma noção de lógica, ainda sou muito leigo em programação.

Fiz uma instalação de wordpress dentro de uma pasta chamada blog, ficando www.meusite.com/blog, e para que o site fosse acessado direto da raiz, copiei o arquivo index.php e informei o novo caminho, para acessar apenas por www.meusite.com

O site carrega normalmente, porém a paginação das postagens exibidas na página inicial da erro:

Por exemplo, no botão pra pág.2, aparece o link meusite.com/page/2/, mas quando se clica, apenas recarrega a página.

Se eu digitar direto no navegador meusite.com/blog/page/2/ aí as demais páginas funcionam com a paginação, exceto se clicar para a 1ª página, que retorna pra raiz do site.

Fuçando no código, descobri o arquivo responsável pela paginação e tentei colocar o endereço completo onde puxa a url:

Original

```
$text = str_replace( $format, number_format_i18n( $page ), $raw_text );
    return "<a href='" . esc_url( $this->get_url( $page ) ) . "'>$text</a>";
}
```

Alterado

```
$text = str_replace( $format, number_format_i18n( $page ), $raw_text );
    return "<a href='/blog" . esc_url( $this->get_url( $page ) ) . "'>$text</a>";
}
```

Deu certo só na primeira página que se clica, porque depois que a página é clicada, quando recarrega retorna http://meusite.com/blog/blog no link das demais páginas...

Alguém já passou por isso ou tem ideia de como solucionar esse erro?

Abaixo segue o código completo desse arquivo:

```
function wp_pagenavi( $args = array() ) {

$defaults = array(
    'before' => '',
    'after' => '',
    'class_active' => 'current',
    'container' => 'div',
    'container_class' => 'pagination-container',
    'menu_class' => 'pagination-menu',
    'style' => 'list',
    'options' => array(
        'pages_text'    => get_setting('pagination_pages_text', __( 'Page %CURRENT_PAGE% of %TOTAL_PAGES%', 'tema' )),
        'current_text'  => get_setting('pagination_current_text', '%PAGE_NUMBER%'),
        'page_text'     => get_setting('pagination_page_text', '%PAGE_NUMBER%'),
        'Primeira_text'    => get_setting('pagination_Primeira_text', __( '&laquo; Primeira', 'tema' )),
        'Última_text'     => get_setting('pagination_Última_text', __( 'Última &raquo;', 'tema' )),
        'prev_text'     => get_setting('pagination_prev_text', __( '&laquo;', 'tema' )),
        'next_text'     => get_setting('pagination_next_text', __( '&raquo;', 'tema' )),
        'dotleft_text'  => get_setting('pagination_dotleft_text', __( '&hellip;', 'tema' )),
        'dotright_text' => get_setting('pagination_dotright_text', __( '&hellip;', 'tema' )),
        'num_pages'     => get_setting('pagination_num_pages', 5),
        'num_larger_page_numbers'   => get_setting('pagination_num_larger_page_numbers', 3),
        'larger_page_numbers_multiple'  => get_setting('pagination_larger_page_numbers_multiple', 10),
        'always_show'   => get_setting('pagination_always_show', false)
    ),
    'query' => $GLOBALS['wp_query'],
    'type' => 'posts',
    'echo' => true
);
$args = wp_parse_args( $args, apply_filters( 'tema_pagination_defaults', $defaults ) );
extract( $args, EXTR_SKIP );

$instance = new PageNavi_Call( $args );

list( $posts_per_page, $paged, $total_pages ) = $instance->get_pagination_args();

if ( 1 == $total_pages && !$options['always_show'] ) return;

$pages_to_show = absint( $options['num_pages'] );
$larger_page_to_show = absint( $options['num_larger_page_numbers'] );
$larger_page_multiple = absint( $options['larger_page_numbers_multiple'] );
$pages_to_show_minus_1 = $pages_to_show - 1;
$half_page_start = floor( $pages_to_show_minus_1/2 );
$half_page_end = ceil( $pages_to_show_minus_1/2 );
$start_page = $paged - $half_page_start;

if ( $start_page <= 0 )
    $start_page = 1;

$end_page = $paged + $half_page_end;

if ( ( $end_page - $start_page ) != $pages_to_show_minus_1 )
    $end_page = $start_page + $pages_to_show_minus_1;

if ( $end_page > $total_pages ) {
    $start_page = $total_pages - $pages_to_show_minus_1;
    $end_page = $total_pages;
}

if ( $start_page < 1 )
    $start_page = 1;

$out = '';
switch ( $style ) {
    // Normal
    case 'list':
        // Text
        if ( !empty( $options['pages_text'] ) ) {
            $pages_text = str_replace(
                array( "%CURRENT_PAGE%", "%TOTAL_PAGES%" ),
                array( number_format_i18n( $paged ), number_format_i18n( $total_pages ) ),
            $options['pages_text'] );
            $out .= "<li><span class='pages'>$pages_text</span></li>";
        }

        if ( $start_page >= 2 && $pages_to_show < $total_pages ) {
            // Primeira
            $Primeira_text = str_replace( '%TOTAL_PAGES%', number_format_i18n( $total_pages ), $options['Primeira_text'] );
            $out .= '<li class="Primeira">' . $instance->get_single( 1, 'Primeira', $Primeira_text, '%TOTAL_PAGES%' ) . '</li>';
        }

        // Previous
        if ( $paged > 1 && !empty( $options['prev_text'] ) )
            $out .= '<li class="previouspostslink">' . $instance->get_single( $paged - 1, 'previouspostslink', $options['prev_text'] ) . '</li>';

        if ( $start_page >= 2 && $pages_to_show < $total_pages ) {
            if ( !empty( $options['dotleft_text'] ) )
                $out .= "<li><span class='extend'>{$options['dotleft_text']}</span></li>";
        }

        // Smaller pages
        $larger_pages_array = array();
        if ( $larger_page_multiple )
            for ( $i = $larger_page_multiple; $i <= $total_pages; $i+= $larger_page_multiple )
                $larger_pages_array[] = $i;

        $larger_page_start = 0;
        foreach ( $larger_pages_array as $larger_page ) {
            if ( $larger_page < ($start_page - $half_page_start) && $larger_page_start < $larger_page_to_show ) {
                $out .= '<li class="smaller page">' . $instance->get_single( $larger_page, 'smaller page', $options['page_text'] ) . '</li>';
                $larger_page_start++;
            }
        }

        if ( $larger_page_start )
            $out .= "<li><span class='extend'>{$options['dotleft_text']}</span></li>";

        // Page numbers
        $timeline = 'smaller';
        foreach ( range( $start_page, $end_page ) as $i ) {
            if ( $i == $paged && !empty( $options['current_text'] ) ) {
                $current_page_text = str_replace( '%PAGE_NUMBER%', number_format_i18n( $i ), $options['current_text'] );
                $out .= "<li class='$class_active'><span>$current_page_text</span></li>";
                $timeline = 'larger';
            } else {
                $out .= '<li class="page ' . $timeline . '">' . $instance->get_single( $i, "page $timeline", $options['page_text'] ) . '</li>';
            }
        }

        // Large pages
        $larger_page_end = 0;
        $larger_page_out = '';
        foreach ( $larger_pages_array as $larger_page ) {
            if ( $larger_page > ($end_page + $half_page_end) && $larger_page_end < $larger_page_to_show ) {
                $larger_page_out .= '<li class="larger page">' . $instance->get_single( $larger_page, 'larger page', $options['page_text'] ) . '</li>';
                $larger_page_end++;
            }
        }

        if ( $larger_page_out ) {
            $out .= "<li><span class='extend'>{$options['dotright_text']}</span></li>";
        }
        $out .= $larger_page_out;

        if ( $end_page < $total_pages ) {
            if ( !empty( $options['dotright_text'] ) )
                $out .= "<li><span class='extend'>{$options['dotright_text']}</span></li>";
        }

        // Next
        if ( $paged < $total_pages && !empty( $options['next_text'] ) )
            $out .= '<li class="nextpostslink">' . $instance->get_single( $paged + 1, 'nextpostslink', $options['next_text'] ) . '</li>';

        if ( $end_page < $total_pages ) {
            // Última
            $out .= '<li class="Última">' . $instance->get_single( $total_pages, 'Última', $options['Última_text'], '%TOTAL_PAGES%' ) . '</li>';
        }
        break;
    // Normal
    case 'simple':
        // Text
        if ( !empty( $options['pages_text'] ) ) {
            $pages_text = str_replace(
                array( "%CURRENT_PAGE%", "%TOTAL_PAGES%" ),
                array( number_format_i18n( $paged ), number_format_i18n( $total_pages ) ),
            $options['pages_text'] );
            $out .= "<span class='pages'>$pages_text</span>";
        }

        if ( $start_page >= 2 && $pages_to_show < $total_pages ) {
            // Primeira
            $Primeira_text = str_replace( '%TOTAL_PAGES%', number_format_i18n( $total_pages ), $options['Primeira_text'] );
            $out .= $instance->get_single( 1, 'Primeira', $Primeira_text, '%TOTAL_PAGES%' );
        }

        // Previous
        if ( $paged > 1 && !empty( $options['prev_text'] ) )
            $out .= $instance->get_single( $paged - 1, 'previouspostslink', $options['prev_text'] );

        if ( $start_page >= 2 && $pages_to_show < $total_pages ) {
            if ( !empty( $options['dotleft_text'] ) )
                $out .= "<span class='extend'>{$options['dotleft_text']}</span>";
        }

        // Smaller pages
        $larger_pages_array = array();
        if ( $larger_page_multiple )
            for ( $i = $larger_page_multiple; $i <= $total_pages; $i+= $larger_page_multiple )
                $larger_pages_array[] = $i;

        $larger_page_start = 0;
        foreach ( $larger_pages_array as $larger_page ) {
            if ( $larger_page < ($start_page - $half_page_start) && $larger_page_start < $larger_page_to_show ) {
                $out .= $instance->get_single( $larger_page, 'smaller page', $options['page_text'] );
                $larger_page_start++;
            }
        }

        if ( $larger_page_start )
            $out .= "<span class='extend'>{$options['dotleft_text']}</span>";

        // Page numbers
        $timeline = 'smaller';
        foreach ( range( $start_page, $end_page ) as $i ) {
            if ( $i == $paged && !empty( $options['current_text'] ) ) {
                $current_page_text = str_replace( '%PAGE_NUMBER%', number_format_i18n( $i ), $options['current_text'] );
                $out .= "<span class='$class_active'>$current_page_text</span>";
                $timeline = 'larger';
            } else {
                $out .= $instance->get_single( $i, "page $timeline", $options['page_text'] );
            }
        }

        // Large pages
        $larger_page_end = 0;
        $larger_page_out = '';
        foreach ( $larger_pages_array as $larger_page ) {
            if ( $larger_page > ($end_page + $half_page_end) && $larger_page_end < $larger_page_to_show ) {
                $larger_page_out .= $instance->get_single( $larger_page, 'larger page', $options['page_text'] );
                $larger_page_end++;
            }
        }

        if ( $larger_page_out ) {
            $out .= "<span class='extend'>{$options['dotright_text']}</span>";
        }
        $out .= $larger_page_out;

        if ( $end_page < $total_pages ) {
            if ( !empty( $options['dotright_text'] ) )
                $out .= "<span class='extend'>{$options['dotright_text']}</span>";
        }

        // Next
        if ( $paged < $total_pages && !empty( $options['next_text'] ) )
            $out .= $instance->get_single( $paged + 1, 'nextpostslink', $options['next_text'] );

        if ( $end_page < $total_pages ) {
            // Última
            $out .= $instance->get_single( $total_pages, 'Última', $options['Última_text'], '%TOTAL_PAGES%' );
        }
        break;
    // Dropdown
    case 'dropdown':
        $out .= '<form action="" method="get">'."\n";
        $out .= '<select size="1" onchange="document.location.href = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">'."\n";

        foreach ( range( 1, $total_pages ) as $i ) {
            $page_num = $i;
            if ( $page_num == 1 )
                $page_num = 0;

            if ( $i == $paged ) {
                $current_page_text = str_replace( '%PAGE_NUMBER%', number_format_i18n( $i ), $options['current_text'] );
                $out .= '<option value="'.esc_url( $instance->get_url( $page_num ) ).'" selected="selected" class="current">'.$current_page_text."</option>\n";
            } else {
                $page_text = str_replace( '%PAGE_NUMBER%', number_format_i18n( $i ), $options['page_text'] );
                $out .= '<option value="'.esc_url( $instance->get_url( $page_num ) ).'">'.$page_text."</option>\n";
            }
        }

        $out .= "</select>\n";
        $out .= "</form>\n";
        break;
}

if( 'list' == $style ) {        
    $out = $before . "<$container class='$container_class'>\n<ul class='$menu_class'>\n$out\n</ul>\n</$container>" . $after;
}
else {
    $out = $before . "<$container class='$container_class'>\n$out\n</$container>" . $after;
}

$out = apply_filters( 'wp_pagenavi', $out );

if ( !$echo )
    return $out;

echo $out;
```

}

class PageNavi_Call {

```
protected $args;

function __construct( $args ) {
    $this->args = $args;
}

function __get( $key ) {
    return $this->args[ $key ];
}

function get_pagination_args() {
    global $numpages;

    $query = $this->query;

    switch( $this->type ) {
    case 'multipart':
        // Multipart page
        $posts_per_page = 1;
        $paged = max( 1, absint( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) );
        $total_pages = max( 1, $numpages );
        break;
    case 'users':
        // WP_User_Query
        $posts_per_page = $query->query_vars['number'];
        $paged = max( 1, floor( $query->query_vars['offset'] / $posts_per_page ) + 1 );
        $total_pages = max( 1, ceil( $query->total_users / $posts_per_page ) );
        break;
    default:
        // WP_Query
        $posts_per_page = intval( $query->get( 'posts_per_page' ) );
        $paged = max( 1, absint( $query->get( 'paged' ) ) );
        $total_pages = max( 1, absint( $query->max_num_pages ) );
        break;
    }

    return array( $posts_per_page, $paged, $total_pages );
}

function get_single( $page, $class, $raw_text, $format = '%PAGE_NUMBER%' ) {
    if ( empty( $raw_text ) )
        return '';

    $text = str_replace( $format, number_format_i18n( $page ), $raw_text );
    return "<a href='/blog" . esc_url( $this->get_url( $page ) ) . "'>$text</a>";
}

function get_url( $page ) {
    return ( 'multipart' == $this->type ) ? get_multipage_link( $page ) : get_pagenum_link( $page );
}
```

}

## http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16973

if ( !function_exists( 'get_multipage_link' ) ) :
function get_multipage_link( $page = 1 ) {
    global $post, $wp_rewrite;

```
if ( 1 == $page ) {
    $url = get_permalink();
} else {
    if ( '' == get_option('permalink_structure') || in_array( $post->post_status, array( 'draft', 'pending') ) )
        $url = add_query_arg( 'page', $page, get_permalink() );
    elseif ( 'page' == get_option( 'show_on_front' ) && get_option('page_on_front') == $post->ID )
        $url = trailingslashit( get_permalink() ) . user_trailingslashit( $wp_rewrite->pagination_base . "/$page", 'single_paged' );
    else
        $url = trailingslashit( get_permalink() ) . user_trailingslashit( $page, 'single_paged' );
}

return $url;
```

}
endif;

Comment: Você tem que colocar na pergunta: 1) detalhes de como configurou o WP para funcionar na raiz; 2) exatamente que arquivo é esse, é do plugin WP Pagenavi?

Answer (score 1):

Não precisa de alterações nos códigos do WP. No próprio site do WP ensinam a fazer o que você deseja. 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory.
Bem fácil.